# array assignment issue

Tags: methods

I am getting a incompatible types required int found:void on this line 
--> moneyCount = countDemoninations(change, denomination[i]). trying to understand why?

```
public class Change {
    int [] denomination = {1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000};
    int moneyCount = 0; 

    public void catagorizeChange(int change){
        for (int i = 0; i < denomination.length; i++){
            moneyCount = countDemoninations(change, denomination[i]);

        }
    }   

    public void countDemoninations(int change, int denomination){
        int moneyCount =0;
        while (change >= denomination){
            moneyCount = moneyCount++;
            change = change - denomination;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a new java student, I want to know if the following edited code below in a good practice i.e have one method used in another where both belong to the same class?

```
    public void countChangedenominations (int change){
        for (int i = 0; i < moneyValuearray.length; i++){
            moneyCountarray[i] = countDemonination(change, moneyValuearray[i]);
        }
    }   

    public int countDemonination(int change, int denomination){
        while (change >= denomination){
            moneyCount = ++moneyCount;
            change = change - denomination; 
        }
        return moneyCount;
```

Comment: In addition to `countDenominations` having to return something to be usable in an asssignment, `moneyCount = moneyCount++;` is a pretty bad idea. In C and C++ it would be undefined behaviour, but as this seems to be Java, the behaviour is defined, however, not what you want. `moneyCount++` increments `moneyCount` **and evaluates to the old value**, so it's the old value that is assigned to `moneyCount`. In other words, `moneyCount` will remain 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem with the line:

```
moneyCount = countDemoninations(change, denomination[i]);
```

is that `countDemoninations` is of type [void](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/void), whereas `moneyCount` is of type `int`.

To solve the issue, change your `countDemoninations` method signature to return `int` instead of `void`, then return `moneyCount` as the last statement in your method:

```
public int countDemoninations( int change, int denomination ) {
    int moneyCount = 0;
    while ( change >= denomination ) {
        moneyCount = moneyCount++;
        change = change - denomination;
    }

    return moneyCount;
}
```